# Wordpress custom button link output after the_content

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-fields

I'm trying to insert a button to show at the end of each post on Wordpress in which the link it goes to is defined by a setup using the custom fields plugin. When creating each post, I am able to select the link I wish to display.

Here is the code I have which I know is wrong but I was hoping someone could help here.

```
function wpb_after_post_content($content){
if (is_single()) {
    $content .= '<a href="'franchise_profile_url'); ?>" target="_blank" class="franchise-profile-btn">Contact Franchise &rarr;</a>';
}
    return $content;
}
add_filter( "the_content", "wpb_after_post_content" );
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume `$franchise_profile_url` is a variable and you should concatenate it in the string like this

```
    $content .= '<a href="'.$franchise_profile_url.'" target="_blank" class="franchise-profile-btn">Contact Franchise &rarr;</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function afterContent($content) {
    if(!is_feed() && !is_home()) {
            $content.= "<div class='footNote'>";
            $content.= "<h4>Click the below button if you like it:</h4>";
            $content.= "<p><a href='#'>LIKE</a></p>";
            $content.= "</div>";
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter ('the_content', 'afterContent');
```

Use the above function. It will help you to achieve what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help here, however, that code simply links back to the post itself and isn't pulling in the URL as set on the post using custom fields. This is the code I had set up before which was working on a default post setup but now I wish to use an alternative method in the functions.php file

```
<?php if( get_field('franchise_profile_url') ): ?>
                 <a href="<?php the_field('franchise_profile_url'); ?>" target="_blank" class="franchise-profile-btn">Contact Franchise &rarr;</a>
            <?php endif; ?>
```